# How to directly compute an integral which corresponds to the normal distribution

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

How does one directly (by finding primitive) compute an integral which corresponds to the normal distribution:

$$\int_{a}^{b}  e^{{-(x-a)^2}/{2s^2}} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: A closed form requires the (nonelementary) error function $\mathrm{erf}(x)$; is that what you want?

Comment: Can I do by explicit finding a primitive without using any additional functions?

Comment: [Risch says no.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0747-7171(85)80037-7)

Comment: @Kolya No. See Risch algorithm

Comment: @Kolya: Wouldn't you be satisfied with an expression of the form $\alpha [\Phi(\beta) - \Phi(\gamma)]$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function?

Comment: Maybe yes. It works.

Comment: $\Phi$ and $\mathrm{erf}$ are essentially equivalent...

Comment: @J. M.: Of course, but probably in elementary courses $\Phi$ is more commonly used.

Comment: @Shai: I suppose; my bias is because I tend to use the error function in my applications more...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to calculate $\int_a^b {e^{ - (x - \mu )^2 /(2\sigma ^2 )} \,dx}$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ stand for the mean and variance of a normal distribution, respectively, then
$$
I:=\int_a^b {e^{ - (x - \mu )^2 /(2\sigma ^2 )} \,dx}  = \frac{{\sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^2 } }}{{\sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^2 } }}\int_a^b {e^{ - (x - \mu )^2 /(2\sigma ^2 )} \,dx}  = \sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^2 } {\rm P}(a \le X \le b),
$$
where $X$ is a Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable. Hence, since $(X - \mu )/\sigma \sim {\rm Normal}(0,1)$,
$$
I  = \sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^2 } {\rm P}\bigg(\frac{{a - \mu }}{\sigma } \le \frac{{X - \mu }}{\sigma } \le \frac{{b - \mu }}{\sigma }\bigg) = \sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^2 } \bigg[\Phi \bigg(\frac{{b - \mu }}{\sigma }\bigg) - \Phi \bigg(\frac{{a - \mu }}{\sigma }\bigg)\bigg],
$$
where $\Phi$ is the distribution function of the Normal$(0,1)$ distribution.