# Definite integral of Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to directly compute an integral which corresponds to the normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37821/how-to-directly-compute-an-integral-which-corresponds-to-the-normal-distribution)

Is there any approximate solution for the following definite integral of normal distribution?

$$\int_{a}^{b}  e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2s^2}} \ dx$$

Comment: See this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF) page for suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and its [approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions)

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_a^b e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\text{erf}\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)\right]$$