# How do I evaluate $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{a} e^{−t^2}dt$?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I [know that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_Integral#By_polar_coordinates)

$$I \equiv \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{−t^2} \, dt=\sqrt{\pi},\text{ and }\int \limits_{-\infty}^0 e^{−t^2} \, dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$

However, I don't understand if (or how) I can find a similar solution for $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{a}e^{−t^2}dt, a \neq 0$, given that the error function actually does not yield closed form solutions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't (except for some approximate expressions if $a$ is either larger or small)

Comment: If you want it to be in closed form, you can define "closed form" to include the error function :)

Comment: If you prefer hypergeometric functions, you could say
${{\rm erf}\left(x\right)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} x\;
{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(1/2;\,3/2;\,-{x}^{2})}
$

Comment: You can't do it in "closed form", but the fact that there are zillions of software packages that do it numerically, and efficiently, might give pause to those who might say "you can't".

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42920/efficient-and-accurate-approximation-of-error-function) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-to-accurately-calculate-erfx-with-a-computer) question.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and answers! I expected this to be the case but your discussion and hints really helped in getting a grip on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $e^{-t^2}$ is an even function, and since you know $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, if you were able to find $\int_{-\infty}^b$ then you would be able to find $\int_a^b$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. The fact that $e^{-t^2}$ does not have an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) primative should suggest to you that you probably can't find $\int_a^b$ explicitly.

As an A-level student (UK 16-18 pre-university), I always wondered why we had to use a table of normal distribution values to get approximate probabilities. Now I know that the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is basically a stretched and translated version of $e^{-t^2}$.

Food for thought: the natural logarithm, $\ln x$, has an integral definition:

$$ \ln x := \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}  $$

because $t^{-1}$ has no known primitive, yet we call $\ln x$ an elementary function, while $\text{erf} \, x$ is not.

Comment: Is "number" a typo?

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks Mike :-)

Comment: Nice food for thought: what we call elementary at some point is of course arbitrary. But then again, I know quite a few simplification rules for logarithm whereas I do not know what to do with a bunch of error functions and of course I was taught logarithms much before error functions so it feels kind of more natural ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this clarification!

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^a \exp(-t^2)\, \text dt = \\
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\int_0^a\exp(-t^2)\, \text dt=\\
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\int_0^a\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{n!} \, \text dt =\\
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}
$$

You can use this to estimate the integral to sufficient accuracy (as GEdgar mentioned, however, this sum converges well when $a \approx 0$ but much slower when $a$ is large).  As was mentioned, no simple "closed form" for this integral exists.

For example, we may approximate $\int_{-\infty}^1 \exp(-t^2)\, \text dt$ with a truncated (6 terms) series:

$$\int_{-\infty}^1 \exp(-t^2)\, \text dt =1.63305\cdots \approx 
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^6 \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}=1.66306\cdots$$

See also [this paper](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Sylvain.Chevillard/download/papers/ChevillardRevolRNC8.pdf) for more strategies.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the paper! Very nice

Answer (score 1):

In probability theory, they sometimes define a function $\Phi$ like this
[image]  ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution))  Yours is a simple change of variables, right?

Comment: The OP has already mentioned their dissatisfaction of the error function $\text{erf}\,x$.