# Is this really true :$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{\operatorname{\\erf(x)}}= n -\alpha$ with $\alpha$ is constant and $n >1$?

Tags: numerical-methods, closed-form, wolfram-alpha, error-function

This is $\int\frac{dx}{\operatorname{\\erf(x)}}$ a simple form integral which i can't to evaluate using variable change and integration by part to get it's form, but some computations in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+dx%2Ferf(x)),+x%3D1+to+5) coming up to me to know one side of it's behavior over the range $(1,n)$ with $n$ is a positive integer such that i have deduced this relation from some computation which i run :

$$\int_1^n \frac{dx}{\operatorname{\\erf(x)}}= n -\alpha$$  with         $\alpha \sim 0.944974758233 \cdots $ and $n >1$ , Now my question here is :

Is really what have got true ? and is this function can be expressed as elementary function ?

Comment: What if $n=1$?...

Comment: Ok, thanks , i have to edit it because in your case is 0

Comment: Not true. What *is* true is $\int_1^n=n-\alpha+\mathcal O(n^{-1})$, with $\alpha:=1+\int_1^\infty(1-\mathrm{erf}(x))\mathrm dx$. It would be nice to obtain the first order correction.

Answer (score 7):

If this was true then it would imply\begin{align*}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\operatorname{\\erf}(x)}&= (n+1 -\alpha)-(n -\alpha)\\&=1\end{align*}
for all $n$, say greater than $1$.

Now this is wrong because $\left[\forall x\in[n,n+1],\frac{1}{\operatorname{\\erf}(x)}>1\right]\Longrightarrow \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\operatorname{\\erf}(x)}>1$

The reason yo got this result is that $\frac{1}{\operatorname{\\erf}(x)}$ is actually [*very close* to $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Derivative_and_integral), so that a computer will not make the difference, if $n$ is large enough. Here *large enough* is not even that large.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

If you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321569/approximating-the-error-function-erf-by-analytical-functions), you will find the nice approximation
$$\text{erf}(x)\approx\tanh \left(\sqrt{\pi }  \log (2)x\right)$$ which makes
$$\int \frac{dx}{\text{erf}(x)}\approx \frac{\log \left(\sinh \left(\sqrt{\pi } \log (2)x\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \log
   (2)}$$
$$I_n=\int_1^n \frac{dx}{\text{erf}(x)}\approx \frac{\log \left(\sinh \left(\sqrt{\pi }  \log (2)n\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \log
   (2)}-\frac{\log \left(\sinh \left(\sqrt{\pi } \log (2)\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi
   } \log (2)}$$ When $n$ becomes large $\sinh(n)\approx \frac {e^x}2$ and, for large $n$ 
$$I_n \approx n-\log (2)-\frac{\log \left(\sinh \left(\sqrt{\pi } \log
   (2)\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \log (2)}\approx n-1.05605$$

For $n=100$, numerical integration leads to $99.055$ while the above gives $98.944$